# Testing $http.get and .post

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, mocking

I want to unit test $http.get and $http.post method in AngularJS using jasmine.
I am trying hard with below code but not getting any success, if someone can help me out.

My code:-

```
(function () {
    angular.module('test').controller('comm', comm);
    comm.$inject = ['$http']
    function comm($http) {
        function init() {
            $http.get('https://localhost:4000/api/getData').then(function (success) {
                $http.post('https://localhost:4000/api/setData', success).then(function (resp) {
                    console.log(resp)
                });
            });
        }
        init();
    }
});
```

Unit test:-

```
describe('', function () {
    var httpBackend;
    beforeEach(module('test'));
    beforeEach(inject(function ($httpBackend) {
        httpBackend = $httpBackend;
        httpBackend.expectGET('https://localhost:4000/api/getData').respond(200,
            { message: 'success' });
        httpBackend.flush();
        httpBackend.expectPOST('https://localhost:4000/api/setData', { message: 'success' }).respond(200,
            { message: 'success' });
    }));

})
```

But I always get an error as 'expected Post https://localhost:4000/api/setData but get https://localhost:4000/api/getData'

Comment: Please check you service-backend type for respective get and post services.

Comment: @D.Pareek yeah its get and post

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/13717 
it says $httpbackend API difficult to use to test multiple request so you have to ensure correctness of both requests.

Comment: @D.Pareek not getting